# USB 3 Flash disk detected as USB 2.10

Tags: linux-mint, usb-drive

I just received SanDisk 64Gb USB 3 Flash Drive.

I tested it in Mac and it detects like USB 3 and gives 140MB/s read performance.

I tested it in Windows in my notebook with dual boot Windows/Ubuntu and it works as USB 3

In Ubuntu, it is recognized as USB 2 and gives me max 40MB/s speed.

I tried with all ports, and all of them are USB 3 BTW.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0eef:7910 D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b36e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 046d:c526 Logitech, Inc. Nano Receiver
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 0781:5583 SanDisk Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Linux Mint 17 Qiana:

```
$ uname -a
Linux **** 3.13.0-53-generic #89-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 20 10:34:39 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

dmesg:

```
$ dmesg | grep usb
[    0.407614] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.407621] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.407654] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.020505] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.020508] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.020511] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.020514] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-53-generic ehci_hcd
[    1.020516] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.0
[    1.036505] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.036508] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.036509] usb usb2: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.036511] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-53-generic ehci_hcd
[    1.036512] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    1.037100] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.037102] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.037103] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.037105] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-53-generic xhci_hcd
[    1.037106] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.037393] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    1.037395] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.037396] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.037398] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-53-generic xhci_hcd
[    1.037399] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.340772] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    1.473260] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024
[    1.473261] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.585035] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    1.717874] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024
[    1.717875] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.793437] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    1.890440] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=07da
[    1.890441] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.961571] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[    2.147720] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b36e
[    2.147721] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[    2.147722] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
[    2.147722] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Chicony Electronics Co.,Ltd.
[    2.147723] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 200901010001
[    2.221878] usb 2-1.6: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    2.316018] usb 2-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=0eef, idProduct=7910
[    2.316021] usb 2-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.316023] usb 2-1.6: Product: eGalaxTouch EXC7903-18v01_Test5
[    2.316025] usb 2-1.6: Manufacturer: eGalax Inc.
[    2.321812] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.321813] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    4.664924] input: eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch EXC7903-18v01_Test5 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/input/input14
[    4.665181] hid-multitouch 0003:0EEF:7910.0001: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v2.10 Device [eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch EXC7903-18v01_Test5] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6/input0
[    4.697286] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    4.702282] input: USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input16
[    4.702358] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    5.110537] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[   25.113768] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   25.131931] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c526
[   25.131933] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   25.131935] usb 3-3: Product: USB Receiver
[   25.131936] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: Logitech
[   25.148165] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.0/input/input19
[   25.148260] hid-generic 0003:046D:C526.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input0
[   25.148706] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.1/input/input20
[   25.148823] hid-generic 0003:046D:C526.0003: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input1
[ 7806.078181] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 7806.095389] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5583
[ 7806.095396] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 7806.095400] usb 3-1: Product: Ultra Fit
[ 7806.095403] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[ 7806.095406] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 4C530001110407100484
[ 7806.125958] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 7806.126079] scsi6 : usb-storage 3-1:1.0
[ 7806.126258] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[ 8011.291942] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 8018.612258] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 8018.629435] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5583
[ 8018.629442] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 8018.629446] usb 3-2: Product: Ultra Fit
[ 8018.629449] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[ 8018.629452] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 4C530001110407100484
[ 8018.629938] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 8018.630185] scsi7 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[ 8297.051982] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[13933.580909] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[13933.598184] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5583
[13933.598191] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[13933.598195] usb 3-1: Product: Ultra Fit
[13933.598198] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[13933.598201] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 4C530001110407100484
[13933.598814] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[13933.599192] scsi8 : usb-storage 3-1:1.0
[13977.229383] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 5
[13984.037631] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[13984.054888] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5583
[13984.054896] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[13984.054900] usb 3-2: Product: Ultra Fit
[13984.054903] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[13984.054906] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 4C530001110407100484
[13984.055395] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[13984.055591] scsi9 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[14014.912847] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[14016.572583] usb 3-3: USB disconnect, device number 2
[14020.415620] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[14020.432778] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5583
[14020.432785] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[14020.432788] usb 3-3: Product: Ultra Fit
[14020.432791] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[14020.432794] usb 3-3: SerialNumber: 4C530001110407100484
[14020.433262] usb-storage 3-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[14020.433415] scsi10 : usb-storage 3-3:1.0
[14066.787793] usb 3-3: USB disconnect, device number 7
[14070.636062] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[14070.654150] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c526
[14070.654156] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[14070.654160] usb 3-3: Product: USB Receiver
[14070.654163] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: Logitech
[14070.656441] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.0/input/input21
[14070.656850] hid-generic 0003:046D:C526.0004: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input0
[14070.658756] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.1/input/input22
[14070.659104] hid-generic 0003:046D:C526.0005: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input1
[14461.104126] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[14461.121336] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5583
[14461.121345] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[14461.121351] usb 3-1: Product: Ultra Fit
[14461.121355] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[14461.121359] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 4C530001110407100484
[14461.121882] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[14461.122145] scsi11 : usb-storage 3-1:1.0
```

lspci:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 650M] (rev ff)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 (rev 24)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
```

[image: Flash Drive detected as USB 2.10]
[image: I have USB 3 detected in System, and all my ports are USB 3]

Comment: `dmesg` from when it was plugged in, and also `lspci` please. Finally, which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Just added info. it is Linux Mint 17 updated from 16.